# Перетаскивание соединенных отрезков или их углов

Tags: алгоритм, графика, вектор, 2d

Есть массив ортогональных отрезков , каждый отрезок представлен точками P1, P2  отрезки соединены друг с другом т.е. точки P1 и P2 пересекается с другими точками P1 и P2 других отрезков.
Получается картинка например следующая
[image: Пример 1]

Соответственно пользователь может таскать эти отрезки и точки углов и соединений.
Точка отрезка которая заканчивается красным считается фиксированной, двигаться она может только если пользователь двигает красный квадрат.

Как в таких случаях описываются ограничения перемещения точек а также связи между отрезками , чтобы двигая например нижний правый угол двигались связанные с ним отрезки.

Comment: Какие пути решения Вы уже попробовали?

Comment: как раз хотел узнать куда нужно копать, т.к. с одной стороны задача достаточно сложная чтоб ее с нуля решать, с другой наверняка уже много раз решенная задача, хотя бы какие ключевые слова

Comment: Вы можете по меткам искать - набирите в "Искать" - [метка][метка]

Comment: Что именно набрать чтобы найти подобный вопрос ? А пользоваться поиском я умею спасибо